# Possible use case of Graphical user interface integration using Vibe.d

Tags: user-interface, d, vibed

One selling point of [Vibe.d](http://vibed.org/) is its **Support for graphical user interfaces**.

So far, I can't fancy a decent use case leveraging this feature and would be very pleased if someone can tell more about it.

Anything related to (Twitter) Stream API for instance?!

---

## Update:

I'm just asking for one example to get started and limit the scope of this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the documentation says: http://vibed.org/features#productivity

---

Graphical user interface integration

Contrary to most other frameworks supporting asynchronous I/O, vibe.d fully integrates with the UI event loop, so that it can be used to power applications with a graphical user interface.

For Windows, there is a native event driver implementation (enable with VibeWin32Driver) that makes use of the MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx function to process window messages together with I/O or concurrency events. For systems running X11, it's possible to use createFileDescriptorEvent to listen on the display connection instead of using XNextEvent.

---

I haven't used vibe.d so I'm not really authorative on this, but I have written similar code before so that description tells me my experience surely applies.

When you are writing a GUI program, one of the difficulties can be remaining responsive to user inputs (window events) while using custom events too - many frameworks do their own event loop to respond to data-ready messages and the GUI application needs an event loop too to respond to stuff like mouse-clicked messages.

vibe.d can use one event loop for both, just meaning you *can* use its async I/O features while handling window messages without needing a separate GUI thread and without blocking on a message mucking up I/O.

I guess a concrete example might be a server application with a control+stats window visible for the administrator.

The case I looked into similar code for was handling console input, GUI input, and network input writing a network enabled terminal emulator. I had to handle incoming ssh packets, key presses, and abort input from the parent terminal all without blocking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "**Server application with a control+stats window**" should say it all I guess. Having also [DGUI](https://bitbucket.org/dgui/dgui) on my radar, hopefully the plumbing code with Vibe.d won't be that too tricky.